# Stock stopped trading, what does this mean?

Tags: stocks, trading, adr

In December I bought ~30 shares of VOLVY (https://www.google.com/finance?cid=608656).  On January 7th it looks like all trading stopped and my broker (TradeKing) says that this is now a worthless asset.

What exactly happened here?  It's clear I made some sort of mistake but I don't fully understand why I am losing my $300.

Comment: Read http://www.volvogroup.com/group/global/en-gb/newsmedia/pressreleases/previous/2006/_layouts/CWP.Internet.VolvoCom/NewsItem.aspx?News.ItemId=4952&News.Language=en-gb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like JP Morgan can convert your holding to [unsponsored ADRs until July.](https://www.adr.com/Site/LoadPDF?CMSID=f52279f0b0634b768207d78ff318560b).

In any event, you should not completely lose the equity. Volvo still exists as a public company, it's just not tradable on US exchanges.

---

Q1: Yes, you'd need a JPM account.  Your broker should have offered a similar service. If they didn't they are not a broker.

Q2: You own 30 shares in Volvo. You need to get your broker to either sell them (off-exchange now) or tell you how to gain access to them.

Comment: A few questions:
1) What exactly does it mean that JPMorgan will convert it?  Do I need a JPMorgan brokerage account to get out of this?
2) When you say I don't lost the equity, what do I have right now and what rights does it give me?

Comment: @hatboysam [Citi's offering the same thing to their customers](https://depositaryreceipts.citi.com/adr/common/file.aspx?idf=3574), as I'd imagine other brokers are.  The fact that your broker is instead telling you your shares are worthless would make me reconsider my relationship with them.

Answer (score 2):

You have not lost value. It is just that the shares you owned, are now not tradable on US stock exchanges. You still have the value of your shares protected. In cases like de-listing of a stock, typically a trust (may be managed by a bank) is setup to help customers liquidate their stocks.

You should try to search the relevant SEC filings for de-listing of this stock to get more details on whom to contact.